# Networkx can't draw a graph from file

Tags: python, pycharm, networkx

I'm new to PyCharm. I'm currently working on a code with networkx that requires me to plot data from a file. I ran the code and PyCharm gives `Process finished with exit code 0` which means no mistake here. But YouTube tutorials with Networkx all show them successfully drawing a graph with the python launcher window, and my python launcher crashes every time I try to run the code. But it only appeared when I'm plotting from an exist file, while graphs can be drawn when adding edges. My console shows nothing except the exit code 0 code. Here is my code

```
import networkx as nx
FileName="locations1.txt"
Graphtype=nx.DiGraph()   


G = nx.read_edgelist(FileName, create_using=Graphtype, nodetype=int, data=.   (('weight',float),))


for x in G.nodes():
  print ("Node: ", x, " has total #degree: ",G.degree(x), " , In_degree: ",        G.out_degree(x)," and out_degree: ", G.in_degree(x))


 for u,v in G.edges():
  print ("Weight of Edge ("+str(u)+","+str(v)+")", G.get_edge_data(u,v))

 nx.draw(G)
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the content of the file?

Comment: I'm new here, so I don't know if I can post file or picture. Anyways it's an txt file converted from a csv file with 5 rows and 5 columns. The problem may be the last two columns contain numbers and other three words...I don't know if it really is the case.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with matplotlib.pyplot library.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
nx.draw(graph)
plt.savefig(path)
```

or

```
nx.draw(graph)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install below decorator version as some of the other version has issues.
https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/4718

```
pip install decorator==5.0.7
```

Here is a sample program to check everything is working fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edge('Person X','Person Y')
g.add_edge('Person X','Person Z')
g.add_edge('Person Z','Person Y')
plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
nx.draw_networkx(g)
```

sample output

[image]